# How Can I Get My File Association to Open Multiple Files in a Single Program Instance?

Tags: windows, shell, registry, associations

I have set up a file extension in the Registry for my program [as Windows requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776883.aspx).

In the Registry, under shell/open/command, I've got:

```
"C:\MyProgramPath\MyProgram.exe" "%1"
```

This works fine for me. When someone clicks on one or more files associated with my application, my application correctly opens the file(s) but each one is opened in a separate program instance.

Is there any way I can do this and open up all files in one program instance?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088510/implement-explorer-contextmenu-and-pass-multiple-files-to-one-program-instance/77605739#77605739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can when using [DDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange). See http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/17787 for an example in Delphi.

**EDIT:**

The link you gave talks about another method: using IDropTarget. This might fit better with your already running drag and drop capabilities.

Comment: At the MSDN page I link to, it says "Note: The DDE method is being deprecated; use the DropTarget method instead." I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the IDropTarget in Delphi. Should I go with DDE anyway?

Comment: Seems IDropHandler is the way to go. Now all I've got to do is figure out how to do that. I've asked another question for help on that at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613333/how-do-i-get-droptarget-to-work-with-my-drop-handler-in-delphi

Answer (score 6):

This is a rather common question, and it has really nothing to do with Windows file extensions. When you doubleclick a file of your program's custom type, Windows will start the associated application `MyProgram.exe` and pass the file name `%1` as a command-line argument.

Now, if you want only a single instance of your application, you need to do this:

1. When your program (`MyProgram.exe`) starts, it should check if there is already an instance of it running.
2. If there is a previous instance, the new instance of `MyProgram.exe` should send a message (of some kind, not necessarily a windows message) to the old instance telling it to open the file `%1`.
3. The new instance should now terminate itself.

## A very simplistic approach

There are several ways of accomplishing this. One of the simplest ways is to set a registry key/value each time your application starts, and remove it when the application exists. Then, when (a new instance of) your application starts, prior to setting this key/value, it should check if it is already set. If, so, follow the steps (2) and (3) above. This might not be the most stable approach (in fact it is a very bad idea, since you cannot guarantee that the app will remove the key/value when it exists if it does so abnormally), but it will give you the basic idea. Other, perhaps better ways, include [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) and, even better, the use of [mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266(VS.85).aspx).

Step two might be implemented by sending a windows message (maybe [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011(VS.85).aspx)), or by setting a registry value, or, by writing a file, or ... There are many ways of communication between different processess.

## The details

Since this is a rather common question, it has been dealt with before. See, for instance, [this Delphi-specific article](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa100703a.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, building this into my program would always prevent multiple instances. But that's not what I want. If file A is clicked on, I want it in instance 1. If then file B is clicked on, then I want it in instance 2. However if both A and B are clicked on in the same click, then they will be 2 parameters passed to the program at once, and I want them both opened in one instance. Why do I want that? So that it will have the same effect as running my program from the command line with 2 parameters, or dragging and dropping 2 files to my program. Thanks, but this doesn't help me.

Comment: @Ikessler: I see. I did not understand that you meant like so. Maybe you should write this in your question?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it earlier, but I didn't realize that it was relevant until you gave your answer. Thanks very much for the time you took to write your detailed answer.