# C# winform opens with right-click context menu, but how do I get the selected item to show up?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu, selecteditem

I have a C# WinForm App that I created to store files in a seperate secure location on the hard drive.  I am trying to add functionality to the program by adding a right-click context menu so when a user right-clicks a file (or group of files) in windows, my program is there in the context for them to select.  No problem there, I have that part worked out.  What I need is to programmatically get that list of files and send it to the program so they are listed in the listbox already.

I am already doing something similar with a multiselect in an OFD, but I dont want them to have to open the program, select browse, find the files and select them when they already have them selected in windows.

There are a ton of programs out that have this functionality (like properties plus, textpad, etc...) I just need a shove in the right direction to help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: You are probably talking about a "shell extension handler".  There's no support for it at all in .NET.  You'll find stuff by googling the quoted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you've already implemented, then all the files *should* appear as arguments on the program's command line. You just need a way of extracting each of those file paths and displaying them in your list view.

In C#, the following code will display a message box containing each argument on the command line:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(string arg in args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(arg);
    }
}
```

But in case you don't want to access these in the `Main` method, you can also use the `Environment` class, which provides the static [`GetCommandLineArgs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx). It returns the same array of strings containing the arguments, and you can loop through it the same way.

Comment: you are brilliant thank you... but... now I am adding each arg to an ArrayList and sending that list to a class. It now opens an instance of my program for each argument, instead of just opening it once for all arguments. what have I done to make that happen.

Comment: See my answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to [customise Right-Click Menu Options in Windows](http://www.jfitz.com/tips/rclick_custom.html)

Then just as #CodyGray says use the `string[] args` in your `Main` method of you program to get the filenames

Answer (score 0):

I am gathering all the arguments and sending them to an ArrayList.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();

        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            myAL.Add(arg);
        }

        ALRec nalr = new ALRec();
        nalr.getArrList(myAL);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

sending it to ALRec Class

```
class ALRec 
{
    ArrayList MyArrLst = new ArrayList();

    public void getArrList(ArrayList AL)
    {
        MyArrLst = AL;
    }
}
```

Why is it starting multiple instances of my App?

Comment: You've confused the syntax highlighting (and me) with your capitalizing conventions. Generally, local and class-level variables are camelCased, while the names of functions are PascalCased. Anyway, this code definitely doesn't start multiple instances of your application. The `Application.Run` command only gets called *once*, which means only one instance is started. The problem is obviously in the way you've registered the context menu handler in the shell. As Hans says, that's probably the more difficult part. My guess is that Windows is creating a new instance of your app for *each* of

Comment: ...the files you've selected, rather than sending them *all* to the same instance on the command line. Can you show us the code you used to add your application to the Registry as a file handler?

Comment: The only registry work I have done is adding the shell command.  hklm\software\classes\*\shell\"Context Menu name"\command.  the string value set up in command is - app.exe "%1"  since I put the app.exe in the system32 folder I did not have to specify a path.

Comment: ...and you are right, it only starts multiple instances of the app when multiple files are selected.  I havent gotten to point yet to see if it adds 1 file to each instance though (as opposed to all files in one, or whatnot).

Comment: @Dave_P: First problem is you added the app to `system32`. That folder isn't for applications. The entire Windows folder is off-limits. Second problem is the way you've added the handler to the Registry. That's a perfectly valid (and the simplest) way of doing it, but the caveat is that it will open a new instance of the app for each file it's registered to handle. It doesn't know it's supposed to pass them all to the same app. You can select 10 *different* file types, and they'll all open in their *own* registered handler apps.

Comment: This question has some information on an alternative approach that will allow you to open multiple selected files in a single instance of your application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605903/how-can-i-get-my-file-association-to-open-multiple-files-in-a-single-program-inst