# How to send multiple files to program with Windows Explorer Right-Click?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry, contextmenu

I add my program executable to Windows Right-Click Context Menu with Windows Registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\programName\command\]
"/path/to/program.exe" "%1"
```

But it has really Awful action. When i right-click on selected files and choose to run with my program, It will open multi instance of my program for each of files !.

I do a lot of googling and i was find some hack to get this work, But i looking for a clean work. There is any argument for registry to support multiple files ?

**NOTE**: I don't want add my program to `SendTo` menu.

Comment: Easy-Peasy: Repair your program to accept multiple files.

Comment: @user2120666, I think you don't read my question correctly. The problem it's not for my program.

Comment: Maybe the answer there is good for your question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088510/implement-explorer-contextmenu-and-pass-multiple-files-to-one-program-instance

Answer (score 0):

### SUMMARY

1. In Registry put the target program as **Context Menu Create File.exe** which writes **reg.txt** file.
2. In your main program loop every 1 second to check if **reg.txt** exists. If it exists, kill the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and delete the **reg.txt** file. Then copy the selected file paths and manipulate with them.
3. If your program loops to check for **reg.txt**, then you need to start the program before executing context menu either on startup or manually.

> I did this with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).
>
> These 2 AutoHotkey scripts below allow you to add a `Open With Chrome` context menu item in Windows Explorer to open multiple selected files.
>
> You can leave all variable values as they are, but if you want to change the `contextMenu` value and `program` name then see **3.1.**

### INSTRUCTIONS:

Create 2 files in the same directory:

1. Create 1st program **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk**

   1. `RunAsAdmin` Label ensures that the script runs as admin (fixes adding Registry values).

      1. The `If (!A_IsAdmin)` checks if current user is **NOT** admin, A_IsAdmin is a built in AutoHotkey variable that returns 1 if user is admin, 0 otherwise.
      2. `Run, \*RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"` ***RunAs** parameter runs the script as admin, **"%A_ScriptFullPath%"** gets the full path of the current executing script.
      3. `ExitApp` exits the current script instance running without admin privileges.
      4. Because the `Run` command runs the script again with admin privileges it will skip the `IF` condition and continue executing code below.
   2. `ContextMenuCreateFile:`  Label creates a **Context Menu Create File.exe** which creates a file **reg.txt** and exits **Context Menu Create File.exe** after it has written the file **reg.txt**. Make sure you specify where your `Ahk2Exe.exe` path is in the `RunWait` command.
   3. `Add To Context Menu:`  Label adds the Registry entry which runs **Context Menu Create File.exe**.

      1. Set the `contextMenu` variable to what needs to be displayed in the Context Menu. (The `program` name is set to `contextMenu`)
      2. Set the `regPath` to your desired Registry path.
      3. When it executes the `MsgBox`, check if the command is added to the Registry in the address bar.
   4. `CreateStartupShortcut:` Label creates the shortcut of the main program **Open With Chrome.exe** in Startup folder.

### Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

AddToContextMenuAndCreateStartupShortcut:
RunAsAdmin:  ; =============RunAsAdmin=============
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
ContextMenuCreateFile:  ; =============ContextMenuCreateFile=============
contextMenuCreateFileAhk := 
(LTrim
"#NoEnv
#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

ContextMenuCreateFile:
FileDelete, reg.txt
FileAppend, , reg.txt
ExitApp
Return"
)  ; contextMenuCreateFileAhk
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.exe  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.exe
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
FileAppend, %contextMenuCreateFileAhk%, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; MAKE Context Menu Create File.ahk
RunWait, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe /in "Context Menu Create File.ahk" /out "Context Menu Create File.exe"  ; Convert AHK to EXE
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
AddToContextMenu:  ; =============AddToContextMenu=============
path := ""  ; path
program := "Context Menu Create File"  ; program
contextMenu := "Open With Chrome"  ; contextMenu
regPath := "HKCR\*\shell"  ; regPath
StringReplace, regKey, contextMenu, %A_Space%, , A  ; regKey
regKey := 0 regKey  ; regKey
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
cmd := 
(LTrim
"reg add """ regPath "\" regKey """ /ve /t REG_SZ /d """ contextMenu """ /f
reg add """ regPath "\" regKey "\command"" /ve /t REG_SZ /d ""\""" path "\""`"" /f"
)  ; Registry
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
FileAppend, %cmd%, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
RunWait, Add To Context Menu.bat, , Hide  ; RUN Add To Context Menu.bat (*RunAs ADMIN)
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; DEL Add To Context Menu.bat
Run, regedit  ; regedit
WinWait, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; Registry
Sleep, 333
ControlSetText, Edit1, %regPath%\%regKey%\command, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlFocus, Edit1, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {Control Down}{NumpadAdd}{Control Up}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {F5}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
MsgBox, 262192, CHECK, Check If Added %contextMenu% To Registry  ; CHECK
CreateStartupShortcut:  ; =============CreateStartupShortcut=============
path := ""  ; path
program := contextMenu  ; program
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
FileCreateShortcut, %path%, %A_Startup%\%program%.lnk  ; Create Startup Shortcut
Run, %A_Startup%, , Max  ; Check If Shortcut Created
Run, "%program%.exe"  ; Run Program
MsgBox, 262144, CHECK, Check If Shortcut Created  ; CHECK
ExitApp  ; ExitApp
Return
```

2. Create 2nd program **Open With Chrome.ahk** which is the main program.

   1. Here a `Loop` is created and checks every 1 second if **reg.txt** exists.
   2. `IfExist, reg.txt` it kills the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and deletes the **reg.txt**.
   3. Then it activates explorer.exe window and copies all selected file paths to **CLIPBOARD**.
   4. `If CLIPBOARD contains .,\` to make sure **CLIPBOARD** contains path **"\"** with extension **"."**.
   5. The list of selected files is saved in `selectedFiles` variable.
   6. The Loop below `chromeParams := ""` loops through selected files, gets the `filePath`s and surrounds them with double quotes, and `StringReplace` replaces the Windows path as url file path ex: `C:\path\file.jpg` to `file:///path/file.jpg`.
   7. Then the `filePath` is concatenated to `chromeParams`.
   8. `StringTrimRight` removes the last space from `chromeParams` string.
   9. Then `Run, chrome.exe %chromeParams%` is executed with `%chromeParams%` (list of selected files). (If the command doesn't open Chrome then put full path to Chrome, ex: `Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` with the same parameters)

### Open With Chrome.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

OpenWithChrome:
Loop  ; Loop Start
{
    Sleep, 1000  ; Fix High CPU
    IfExist, reg.txt  ; IF reg.txt EXIST
    {
        RunWait, cmd /c taskkill /im "Context Menu Create File.exe" /f, , Hide  ; Fix Opening 2 Compose Windows
        FileDelete, reg.txt  ; DEL reg.txt
        WinActivate, ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe  ; Explorer
        CLIPBOARD := ""  ; Clear Clipboard
        Send, {Control Down}{c}{Control Up}  ; Copy File Paths
        ClipWait, 0  ; Clip Wait
        If CLIPBOARD contains .,\  ; IF CLIPBOARD contains .,\
        {
            selectedFiles := CLIPBOARD  ; selectedFiles
            chromeParams := ""  ; chromeParams
            Loop, Parse, selectedFiles, `n, `r  ; Loop Start selectedFiles
            {
                filePath := """file:///" A_LoopField """"  ; filePath
                StringReplace, filePath, filePath, \, /, A  ; Replace \ with /
                chromeParams .= filePath . " "  ; chromeParams .= %filePath%,
            }
            StringTrimRight, chromeParams, chromeParams, 1  ; Remove Last Space
            Run, chrome.exe %chromeParams%  ; Open Files In Chrome
        }
    }
}
Return
```

3. Convert both **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk** and **Open With Chrome.ahk** to **EXE** files in the same directory using **Ahk2Exe.exe** --> (find in Start Menu, just browse file and hit convert)
4. Execute the **`Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.exe`**
5. Select files, right click and the **Open With Chrome** context menu item should appear.