# How to collect arguments from multiple instances of autohotkey script and pass it to handler script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line-arguments, autohotkey, multiple-instances

The actual thing I did and want to do:

1. I have a autohotkey script `1.ahk` that do something with directory, something like:

   ```
   #Requires Autohotkey v2.0
   if(A_Args.length > 0){
       srcFolderPath := A_Args[1]
       DoSomethingWithPath(srcFolderPath)
   }
   ```
2. I add a custom contextmenu item (windows 10) for it in `HKCR\Directory\shell\DoThing\command`, the value is `"C:\App\AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Script\1.ahk" "%1"`, then when I select a folder `folder1` then right click and choose `DoThing`, `1.ahk` is called and received the full path of `folder1` as argument
3. However when I select multiple folders `folder1` ... `folder99` then right click and select `DoThing`, `1.ahk` is called 99 times, there're possible 99 overwrite/readonly warning which I wanto avoid
4. [Goal] I want `1.ahk` to receive an array of arguments that contains 99 path strings instead of call `1.ahk` 99 times when I select 99 folders and click `DoThing`, change `1.ahk` to

   ```
   #Requires Autohotkey v2.0
   if(A_Args.length > 0){
       srcFolderPathArray := A_Args
       DoSomethingWithPathArray(srcFolderPathArray)
   }
   ```

If possible I want avoid method like "99 instances write to temp.txt and `1.ahk` read it"

Or is it possible to pass all arguments as array in the beginning?

Thanks for any help of advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement Explorer ContextMenu and pass multiple files to one program instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088510/implement-explorer-contextmenu-and-pass-multiple-files-to-one-program-instance)

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful, if I read it correctly, I can use sendto, or write a shellextension, or use a program that handles it. Sendto is good but it has some problem with autohotkey (ahk side I suppose), shellext looks too complicated for me...so I found a small program that can solve this: https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher. It kind of solved THIS question but unfortunately did not solve my problem cuz I encountered another problem...I'll create another question

Comment: Round 2 here: [Move files/folder from multiple source into one target path using windows shell script in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421478/move-files-folder-from-multiple-source-into-one-target-path-using-windows-shell)