# Move files/folder from multiple source into one target path using windows shell script in autohotkey

Tags: directory, windows-10, autohotkey, windows-shell

Background: I want to write an ahk script to extract content of selected folder to the parent level.

The first technical problem is solved (kind of): [how to pass multiple arguments to script instead of call the script multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420789)

Then I was blocked by the second also the final problem: how to use this file path array

The original script is here

```
    srcFolder := A_Args[1]
    targetFolder := substr(srcFolder, 1, instr(srcFolder, '\',, -1) - 1)
    comobject('shell.application').namespace(targetFolder).movehere(srcFolder . '\*')
```

Why use shell.application? Because I want to use the fancy GUI of windows to handle file overwrite/readonly alert and so on.

It was called by context menu command and create an instance for every selected folder, the length of `A_Args` is always 1

Now our new `A_Args` is an array of selected folder path, they share a same parent folder (it's worth noting that it's possible not all children in this parent folder is selected)

When I try to update the script I found that `movehere` do support [`folderitems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitems) which is multiple folders as we need. However, I didn't found any "concat","additem" or similar method of `folderitems`, there's no way to concat all `folderitems` generate from each path of `A_Args` into one `folderitems` and pass it to `movehere`

If I call `movehere` for each of them, that will be the same as call multiple instance of the script...(the overwrite warning might be popup 99 times instead of showing a window displaying 99 overwrite entries)

The script I want to get:

```
    srcFolders := A_Args ; path array
    anySrcFolder := srcFolders[1] ; A_Args index start from 1
    targetFolder := substr(anySrcFolder , 1, instr(anySrcFolder , '\',, -1) - 1)
    
    srcFoldersComObj := MagicWayToConcatFolderItemsObject(srcFolders)

    comobject('shell.application').namespace(targetFolder).movehere(srcFoldersComObj)
```